# NHibernate Profiler - cached entities

Tags: c#, asp.net, nhibernate, profiler

I've just implemented SysCache2 and activated caching for some of the entities in my solution.
Everything is working fine, but i do have one question:

Sometimes when im browsing a specific page, NHibernate Profiler shows a very high number of cached entities being fetched. A couple of hundred cached entities should be a fair amount that would be used, but sometimes it counts up to 3000-5000. See image below.

In this case, are 5002 entities really being fetched from the cache, or is there a misprint in NHibernate Profiler?

Loading-wise, everything seems ok. The page request has finished, but the profiler keeps counting up more and more cached entities.

Anyone experienced anything similiar or does this really occur?

[image: NHibernate Profiler Cache]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's really fetching all the entries. Also, you're screenshot is cropped, but I'm assuming that you're receiving an alert from NHProf stating that there are too many cache calls.

NH has two different types of cache: the query cache and entity cache. The query cache only stores the identity of the items which resulted from the query (i.e, no data). Then NH has to fetch the items individually from the entity cache by ID.

More info at: http://ayende.com/blog/3112/nhibernate-and-the-second-level-cache-tips

Be careful that this may impact performance at the web-server. I had the exact same situation as you, and had better results disabling the second-level cache for these entities.

Also, it keeps showing new entries even after the page has loaded due to some latency between the appender and NHProf. The appender sends all the log to NHProf, and it takes some time for it to draw all the info.

Comment: The problem was me initializing the profiler every time a session was created. Now the cached entities are displayed correctly.

Comment: By the way psousa, how come you had better result with no cache enabled?

Comment: It's rather simple. My application server was a very basic Virtual Machine without much RAM or CPU. The Database server was a very capable physical machine with good specs. During my load-tests, and with several users fetching and writing information, the CPU easily reached 100% with the cache enabled, because of some screens which loaded thousands of items from cache. And like I said above, NHProf itself warns you that you shouldn't load too many items from cache. I even profiled the execution with DotTrace, and it spends much time indeed fetching and writing from the second-level cache.

Comment: Im using SysCache2, thus the cache is not distributed. NHibernate only warns this in distributed environments. But i will keep an eye open for CPU usage. The site is still slow, but it probably depends on all the rendering from Telerik web controls :-)